# WORDPRESS: Display list of Sub-Categories and the posts they contain, within one main Category

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-list-categories

I've found tons of code and plugins to do various things; from show posts for specific cats, subcats of a cat, etc.. BUT, I cannot for the life of me find, nor do I know the WP API well enough to do what I need with it..

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

Display a UL of all subcats within Cat31, and the posts for each of those subcats:

SubCat1
  Post 1
  Post 2

SubCat2
  Post 1
  Post 2

SubCat3
  Post 1
  Post 2

It's pretty straight forward, but all the loops I have tried fail either at the subcat loop or the post loop (one or the other works, I cannot get them both to work..)

So, unless I can find a plugin to do this (I'd prefer to code this into a template file!) then I need to figure out how to:

Loop Subcats within Cat31
  while looping subcasts, loop posts for each subcat

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you post this into http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. I think you are far more likely to get a WP api response there. Certainly possible in my experience, but haven't done this myself.

Comment: Excellent.. thanks for the heads up! I didn't realize they had added that to the network LOL.. now posted there as well.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think here's what you need.

```
$categories=  get_categories('child_of=10');  for each  $categories as $category {
      //Display the sub category information using $category values like $category->cat_name
      $posts_array = get_posts( 'category=$category->cat_ID' );
      for each $posts_array as $post {
           //Display the posts information using $post values like $post->post_title
      }  }
```

You just need to format them. Hope this would be of help.

Comment: Thanks you for the lead !! I'm working with the code now, and am running into something I can't pin down : The sub cat shows correctly.. but there is only one post in the subcat yet I have a list of posts, all with that 'real' posts name.. but linking to all other posts I have in the site! Must have to do with the category=$category->cat_ID or something controlling the cat the posts loop is looking for..

Comment: Ran out of space.. here is the actual code I am using (after closing up the foreach() functions)
`$categories=  get_categories('child_of=31');  
foreach  ($categories as $category) {
 //Display the sub category information using $category values like $category->cat_name
 echo '<h2>'.$category->name.'</h2>';
 echo '<ul>';

 $posts_array = get_posts( 'category=$category->cat_ID' );
 foreach ($posts_array as $post) {
  echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';   
 }  
 echo '</ul>';

}`

Comment: you should also put $post->ID inside the get_the_title()...or you may instead, directly access $post member like $post->post_title, $post->permalink (please check WP codex for actual member name)

Answer (score 3):

@Free Lancer,
Thanks again.. after working with your code for a bit, I was able to make it work. Some of the changes included:

'for each' changed to `foreach`

`foreach` statements wrapped in ()

I also changed the `'category=$category->cat_ID' to 'cat='.$category->term_id`

lastly, I changed the foreach loop on the posts and added `setup_postdata( $post );` to that loop.

For all that need a snippet that will display a list of subcategories, within a specified category, AND show all the posts within each of those subcats.. here it is:

```
$categories =  get_categories('child_of=31');  
foreach  ($categories as $category) {
        //Display the sub category information using $category values like $category->cat_name
        echo '<h2>'.$category->name.'</h2>';
        echo '<ul>';

        foreach (get_posts('cat='.$category->term_id) as $post) {
            setup_postdata( $post );
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';   
        }  
        echo '</ul>';
    }
```

Thanks again for all the help and pointing me in the right direction !!